# Can't autostart x11vnc when start/reboot PC ( Lubuntu 20.04 LTS)

Tags: server, lubuntu, services, vnc, autostart

I installed x11vnc and started success, but not start service VNC when start/reboot PCs

`nano /lib/systemd/system/x11vnc.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Start x11vnc at startup.
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -auth guess -forever -loop -noxdamage -repeat -rfbauth /etc/x11vnc.pass -rfbport 5900 -shared

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
################################################
sudo systemctl enable x11vnc.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using Ubuntu 20.10 64-bit on a headless server in my home cloud. I agree having X11VNC autostart from occasional reboots is like paradise in the clouds (pun intended).

Spawning a systemd service daemon should solve your X11VNC autostart from boot as it is backwards compatible with Ubuntu 15.04 to 20.04. systemd has been the service daemon from Ubuntu 15.04 on.
[image]
*This is a window of Remmina VPN/RDP viewer on a remote Ubuntu 20.04 64-bit PC

You can proceed to **[YourFriendCaspian](https://gist.github.com/YourFriendCaspian/a1dc3b01c5423ee10893d74f9b172df9)** for his very well written guide to automating X11VNC at startup.

But allow me to paraphrase Caspian's post here:

> ### Ubuntu 15.04 – Configure your system to have x11vnc running at startup.
>
> Hello World,
>
> If you are following us, you probably remember that we wrote already a
> post about this topic (see Ubuntu 14.10 – Configure your sytem to have
> x11vnc running at startup). Since Ubuntu 15.04 is using systemd, the
> instructions found in the previous post are not applicable anymore.
> Some of our readers had issues after upgrading to Ubuntu 15.04. The
> x11VNC is not running at startup anymore.
>
> This post will provide the necessary information to have x11vnc
> running at startup on ubuntu 15.04 when systemd is used.
>
> ### Our Goal
>
> At the end of this post, you should be able to connect via vnc to your
> Ubuntu machine even if there is a reboot and even if no user are
> logged into the machine. This configuration should display the login
> screen via vnc viewer client you are using.
>
> We didn’t invent anything here. All the information provided here are
> based on the information made available at this location :
> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers#Have_x11vnc_start_automatically_via_systemd_in_any_environment_.28Vivid.2B-.29
>
> ### Installing x11vnc server
>
> In this post, we have decided to use the x11vnc server package to
> provide vnc capabilities. The installation process is quite straight
> forward. Log into your ubuntu 15.04 machine, open the terminal console
> and issue the following command :
>
> $ sudo apt-get install x11vnc
>
> To have a minimum of security, we will protect the vnc connection via
> a password. The password will be stored in a file. To create this
> file, you will need to issue the following command :
>
> $ sudo x11vnc –storepasswd /etc/x11vnc.pass
>
> You will be asked to enter a password. Enter the password and confirm
> your choice and you should be good to go.
>
> ### Create the Service Unit file
>
> So far, we have just issued standard command related to the x11vnc
> package.  We need to create the service unit file for our x11vnc
> service.  To do this, we will issue the following command :
>
> $ sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/x11vnc.service
>
> This file should content the following lines
>
> [Unit] Description=Start x11vnc at startup. After=multi-user.target
> [Service] Type=simple ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -auth guess -forever
> -loop -noxdamage -repeat -rfbauth /etc/x11vnc.pass -rfbport 5900 -shared [Install] WantedBy=multi-user.target Save the file
>
> ### Configure Systemd
>
> It’s time to issue the command to have systemd aware of the change and
> make the service running at startup.  In a command prompt, you will
> issue the following command :
>
> $ sudo systemctl daemon-reload $ sudo systemctl enable x11vnc.service
> Restart the system and do not login.  We will check if this is
> working…..
>
> ### Testing the solution
>
> To check that you can indeed perform a vnc connection to your Ubuntu
> Machine, you will try to connect to it using your favourite vncviewer
> (we are using TigerVnc) while nobody is connected and just after a
> reboot of the machine.
>
> In the vncviewer, you will provide the ip address or hostname of the
> machine to connect and the port to be used. In our example, the port
> used is 5900.  If you have set a password to protect your vnc
> connection, you will be prompted for a password as well.
>
> If everything is ok, you should see the Ubutun login page displayed
> inside your vncviewer
>
> ### Final Notes
>
> And voila! We have sucessfully updated the instructions on how to have
> x11vnc run at startup. As you can see, since Ubuntu 15.04 is using the
> Systemd solution, we need to create our service unit files
> (x11vnc.service), register them with systemctl and we are done.

Please give credit to Caspian!! :D